# Insert footer image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, footer

I have the following Worpress theme ([**http://alethemes.com/socha/**](http://alethemes.com/socha/)) and I am trying to insert a Footer image into it. I have tried the following code in the Appearance -> Editor -> footer.php but all that happens is the text in the alt="Image Description" is displayed in the footer section - no image. For the image source I have uploaded the image to Wordpress and I have copied the images link URL as defined in Media -> Media Library. The URL in the code below is just an example of the URL and not the actual URL.

```
</div>
<footer id="footer-main" role="contentinfo">
    <?php if (ale_get_option('copyrights')) : ?>
        <p class="copy"><?php echo ale_option('copyrights'); ?></p>

        <!-- My Footer Image Here -->
        <img src="http://mydomain.com/myimagefolder/image.format" alt="Image Description">

    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="copy">&copy; <?php _e('2013. Socha Responsive Theme. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.', 'aletheme')?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="topbutton">
        <a href="#top" id="gotop"><?php _e('TOP', 'aletheme')?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cf"></div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
```

I have also tried inserting the code above in Appearance -> Theme Options -> Themes -> Copyright but again all that is dipslayed is the text in the alt="Image Description".

Can anyone tell me how I can insert the footer image?

Comment: Maybe try with `<img src="http://mydomain.com/myimagefolder/image.format" alt="Image Description"/>` ? Seems like there's a dash missing

Comment: Tried that but does not work either. Still get the same results as described above. Only the text in alt="" is displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress can't find your image. Is this definitely the location of your uploaded image? If you uploaded via the WP uploader, it will be in the 'uploads' directory.

Try using;

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/myimagefolder/image.format" />
```

Using Wordpress's built in get_template_directory() function will make sure that if the URL changes, Wordpress will find the image.

Also, make sure to put the image width and height attributes into the  tag.